# Split URI and get The number back in C# PokeApi Blazor WASM.net 5

Tags: c#, blazor, webassembly, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to split the a uri to get the number out of a link that looks like this
`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/201/`
so the uri looks like that url.
I know how I can add it to the end of this  link `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/` to get the sprite I am looking for and I have tried to understand the other answers but it is so complicated. I just need something simple like split(./) last indexof - 1 type thing but I could not figure that out. I know I will be getting a minus for asking this question but I am exhausted thanks :)

Comment: What’s the input and expected output? Do you expect 201 from the first link?

Comment: have you tried segments? `new Uri("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/201/").Segments`

Comment: Yes I expect the 201 without / I'm sorry I thought I wrote that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you want the /201 number. There are a few ways, if you want an easy one, I would do:

```
string url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/201/";
var splitUrl = url.Split('/');
var sprite = splitUrl[splitUrl.Length - 2];
```

But this is just assuming the number is always at the end with a trailing slash.

Sorry for lack of formatting, posting from mobile.

Comment: Yes the number should always be at the end of the url thanks I'll try it out later today

Comment: All I need is the number but I can get away with the / too